# Missing tex in eps files in latex

Tags: latex, pdf-generation, ps, pdflatex

When I use the following commands

```
latex thesis.tex
dvips thesis.dvi
ps2pdf thesis.ps

and acroread thesis.pdf
```

Some of the tex in eps files used in the thesis is missing?

Could some one solve this issue?

Comment: Solved the problem by adding this line \usepackage{pslatex}     % to use PostScript fonts

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by adding this line \usepackage{pslatex} % to use PostScript fonts